# Can I get mod_wsgi to work with a 64-bit Apache/Python install?

Tags: python, apache, 64-bit

first, I'd like to say I've been lurking on this site for years and love it. For the first time, I feel like I've encountered a problem that hasn't been addressed on StackOverflow before, so here goes.

I am trying to get python to work on my 64-bit Wampserver  install on Windows 7. I have a 64-bit version of python 2.7 running as well. However, I can't find a 64-bit version of mod_wsgi.so, which I understand is what I need. Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

You may have to use that Apache distribution though.

Comment: hello, how can i get  .so file out of .whl file?

Comment: It is a zip file. Rename ``.whl`` extension to ``.zip`` if you need to and then extract it with an archiver tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could always compile from source.

Even if you do that you'll have to get 64 bit apache too, since ASF doesn't ditribute 64 bit windows binary. Are you sure you've got 64 bit one installed?

Comment: compiling those things from source is a shitload of work on windows

Comment: i think that's why there's more LAMP than WAMP ;)